# Centered text in TextField is slightly offset

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => ExampleScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue.empty.copyWith(text: '8')),
              autofocus: false,
              style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline2!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hey,

I'm trying to center text in a TextField. As you can see, the text is slightly offset to the top left. Is there something else I have to consider in order to center the text?

edit: This has nothing to do with the rest of the widget tree. You can reproduce this issue on dartpad.dev using only the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue in the Flutter GitHub repository and it has been confirmed that this is indeed a bug.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92407

Answer (score 0):

While you are using `Container`,

use  `alignment: Alignment.center,`

```dart
 Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: TextField(
             controller: controller,
             focusNode: focusNode,
            autofocus: false,
            style: theme.primaryTextTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
             color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.disabledColor),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

More about [Container-class.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

Comment: Setting an aligment does not do anything in this case, because the Containers size is constrained by its parent widget. When the Container does not have an alignment, the Container passes the constraints from the parent to the TextField and sizes itself to match the TextField. Thereby, the TextField is already centered inside the Container.

Comment: Can you include its parent widgets? How the `TextField` becomes circular shape?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the parent widgets. You can reproduce the issue on dartpad.dev using only the code above. Check my edit.

Comment: Does it mean the only thing contain in body is this `Container...` widget?

Comment: It means that my actual Widget tree contains hundreds of Widgets, but this particular issue reproduces even if the Container widget is at the beginning of the Widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

Change 2 to correct value like this

decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),

Comment: It is technically possible to center the text using this method, however that would only be a workaround. Also, the amount of offset is relative to the size of the container, so whenever I wanna change the containers size, I would have to manually figure out the right amount of padding for the new container size to have the text centered again.